# How can I setup Spring MVC and Spring EJB integration beanRefContext.xml using a configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I am trying to setup Spring MVC and also I want to inject Spring beans into my EJB componets.

I setup web.xml file as bellow:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.callcenter.configuration.SpringConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

SpringConfig looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.callcenter.mvc")
public class SpringConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
        final InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean userBean(){
        final JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("java:global/callcenter/UserBeanImpl");
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }


}
```

Injecting a EJB into a Spring Controller is working just fine but injecting a Spring Managed Bean into a EJB is not.

Following the documentation I created two xml files:

- beanRefContext.xml

  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  ```
  <bean id="businessBeanFactory" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
      <constructor-arg value="businessApplicationContext.xml" />
  </bean>
  ```

And businessApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.callcenter.service"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.callcenter.ejb"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>


</beans>
```

My EJB looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(UserBean.class)
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class UserBeanImpl implements UserBean {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User findUser(Long id) {
        return userService.findUser(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Long save(User user) {
        return userService.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Long id) {
        userService.remove(id);
    }

}
```

PS: Before some ones questions why I am doing like that (to complex for what you are trying to achieve) that is just a POC.

When I call the controller the exception bellow was thrown:

```
12:22:09,404 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
12:22:09,408 INFO  [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7ddf9485: startup date [Fri Sep 27 12:22:09 BRT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
12:22:09,417 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3603845b: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
12:22:09,418 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component UserBeanImpl for method public abstract com.callcenter.domain.User com.callcenter.ejb.UserBean.findUser(java.lang.Long): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:80) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:179) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:179) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar:1.0.5.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.findUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.callcenter.mvc.UserController.findUser(UserController.java:37) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:439) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:66) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessSessionComponent$1.create(StatelessSessionComponent.java:63) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.AbstractPool.create(AbstractPool.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.pool.strictmax.StrictMaxPool.get(StrictMaxPool.java:123) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to return specified BeanFactory instance: factory key [null], from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:402) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.getBeanFactoryReference(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:156) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.getBeanFactory(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:137) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.doAutowireBean(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:117) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.autowireBean(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:97) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:118) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:276) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:397) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 89 more
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substituting the line:

```
<constructor-arg value="businessApplicationContext.xml" />
```

with the following

```
<constructor-arg value="classpath*:businessApplicationContext.xml" />
```

in *beanRefContext.xml* and adding the following line:

```
<context:spring-configured/>
```

just after the line:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

in *businessApplicationContext.xml*.